# Mongoose Ignore Required

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this `User` schema:

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

When you do a POST (`/api/user-add`), I want all the fields to be required. But when I do a login (`/api/login`) then I only need the `email` and `password` fields. My problem is, in my login code I eventually get to this function:

```
staffSchema.methods.generateToken = function(callback) {
    var token = jwt.sign(this._id.toHexString(), config.SECRET);

    this.token = token;
    this.save(function(err, staff) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, staff);
    });
}
```

And here it thows an error because the `name` field is required. How do I bypass this. I am looking for something like this I assume:

```
    this.save(function(err, staff) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, staff);
    }).ignoreRequired('name');
```

Comment: Why you call save() on login()

Comment: Because you need to save the token that is generated, or what would you propose?

Comment: Please add new  collection for store token is good practice

Comment: If you need example I can provide you?

Comment: Yes please that would be helpful :)

Comment: Why `save`? You need to use `findOneAndUpdate` the `token` field. @FreddyBonda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You Login using `JWT` token this is a basic example to generate `token` and authenticate `user` without store `token`

Note :

> Example to authenticate the user without store `token` in DB

***Login Method**

```
const jwt = require('./jwt');
userCtr.authenticate = (req, res) => {
  const {
    email, password,
  } = req.body;

  const query = {
    email: email,
  };

  User.findOne(query)
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        //return error user not found.
      } else {
        if (passwordHash.verify(password, user.password)) { // verify password
            const token = jwt.getAuthToken({ id: user._id });
            const userData = _.omit(user.toObject(), ['password']); // return user data
            return res.status(200).json({ token, userData });
        }

        //return error password not match
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
};
```

***jwt.js**

```
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const logger = require('./logger');

const jwtUtil = {};

jwtUtil.getAuthToken = (data) => {
  return jwt.encode(data, process.env.JwtSecret);
};

jwtUtil.decodeAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    try {
      return jwt.decode(token, process.env.JwtSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

module.exports = jwtUtil;
```

***use middleware to prevent another route to access**.

```
userRouter.post('/update-profile', middleware.checkUser, userCtr.updateProfile);
```

***middleWare.js**

```
middleware.checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const { headers } = req;

  if (_.isEmpty(headers.authorization)) {
    //return error
  } else {
    const decoded = jwt.decodeAuthToken(headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', ''));
    if (decoded) {
      User.findOne({ _id: decoded.id })
        .then((user) => {
          if (user) {
            req.user = user;
            next();
          } else {
            //error
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //errror
        });
      req.user = decoded;
    } else {
      //error
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Pretty complex stuff for me haha but I thank you my friend!